# SQL Thesaurus like behaviour without Full-text Search

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion, synonym, thesaurus

My search engine is written using mySQL and ColdFusion, the main part of is where I loop the following (or similar) on each search term separated by spaces.

```
AND productname REGEXP '(\\b#trim(search)#\\b)'
```

I'd like to introduce alternatives words, so that when any one of these are searched the rest are included

> M43, M4/3, Micro-Four-Thirds, MFT

I could use a separate query to get a list of matching keywords and loop in an OR - but this seemed a little unrefined.

My database is a list of camera product names with little consistency, I tested full-text search but was not happy with the results.

So is there an 'Theasaurus' like option without the need of Full-text search implementation?

Comment: For a predefined shortlist of known alternatives, I would just concatenate them on the left hand side of the comparison, so that you are looking for `search` to match among all of the `productname` alternatives, rather than trying to substitute `search` many times for matches against the one `productname`. You could store the alternatives in a separate table and pull them in with a join, subquery or udf, or you could denormalize by storing the alternatives as an extra column on the product to simplify the search query.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just going over what you said in my head and I'm starting to build a picture.

Also the talk of concatenation made me think of this as another back up idea..
REGEXP '\\b#trim(search)#\\b|\\b#trim(altsearch1)#\\b|\\b#trim(altsearch2)#\\b|'

Comment: Yes that is also valid, although my experience of doing similar for product searches for online stores, is that moving the pre-determined known alternatives to the left hand side and reducing the number of `OR` comparisons, resulted in better performance - with the data I was dealing with anyway. I would reserve those regex ORs for inexact alternatives like when implementing stemming - eg taking the user's search term and automatically searching for singular/plural and different conjugations and tenses.

Comment: ie if you know all the alternative names for a product then store them against the product - it's not really any different to people having a `keywords` column on the product table and stuffing whatever they want to match against in there, except that can result in duplicated data. What I was suggesting earlier, applied to your code, was effectively `AND concat(productname, ' ', productAlternativeNames, ' ', productDescription)  REGEXP '(\\b#trim(search)#\\b)'`

Comment: Many Thanks Sev, I will have a go to implement it.

Comment: @SevRoberts I went with the keywords column, and concat_ws(' ', productname, productkeywords) thanks, I tried to look at having a table for synonyms but the logic of implementing it felt chicken and egg and my brain was fried.

Answer (score 0):

I added a product keyword field, which I populated with alternative keywords.

My SQL where clause has now loops the terms and compares against the concatenated product name and keywords

```
 AND concat_ws(' ', productname, productkeywords) REGEXP '(\\b#trim(search)#\\b)'
```

Thanks to @SevRoberts for this solution